# How to plot data points with two y values?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been searching for this answer for a while now and although there are some that come near, but I have yet to find the right solution.

I want to plot a line chart of water levels over time. I want to have the depth (ex: 25m) y axis on one side and the height above sea level (ex: 1300m) on the other. There should be only one line with data points on the chart.

At the moment the config looks like this:

```
var config = {
    title: {
        text: 'Borehole Water Level'
    },
    options: {
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var tooltip = '<b><u>' + boreholename + '</u></b>';

                $.each(this.points, function() {
                    tooltip += '<br/><strong>Date : </strong>' + BaseService.formatDate(this.x);
                    tooltip += '<br/><strong>' + this.series.name + ': </strong>' +
                    this.y + 'm';
                });
                return tooltip;
            },
            shared: true
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Depth [m]'
        }
        }, {
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Level above sea [m]'
            }
        }],
        series: [{
            name: 'Water Level depth',
            data: chartdata,
        }, {
            name: 'Water Level above sea level',
            data: chartdata2,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    };
    return config;
};
```

At the moment I have two separate lines but I only want one.

Comment: is this [example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes) solves your need

Comment: Almost but on that example the two y axis correspond to two different plot lines. I only have one set of data but want two y axis for the same data point. The answer below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want would be to link the second yAxis to the first one and modify labels of the second using `formatter`.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/d9ruh9n1/

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No problem :). If answer was useful, please consider to accept it. Regards.